# How to forward the .config file to remote host together with the agent?

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I have a GitLab server configured on a non-standard port. I am using ssh protocol to clone and push, and I have configured the correct port entry in the .config file of ssh.

Now, I need to connect to the GitLab server from a remote pc. I want to use the forward agent functionality to avoid creating a new public/private key on the PC and a new remote config file.

The forward agent option seems to work just fine (i.e. ForwardAgent Yes). However, the "config" of the GitLab server is not forwarded to the remote server. Is there a way to also provide to the remote server the local config file?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to copy the configuration file to the other machine or use other means to configure ssh on the remote machine.